# How to remove dynamically inserted code in my WordPress site?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess, malware

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: -136px; overflow: auto; width:1241px;">
<h3><strong><a style="font-size: 11.335pt;" href="http://2giadinh.com/thoi-trang">thời trang 
trẻ em</a></strong>
<strong><a style="font-size: 11.335pt;" href="http://themestotal.com">Wordpress Themes
 Total Free</a></strong>
<em><a style="font-size: 10.335pt;" href="http://2xaynha.com">tư vấn xây nhà</a></em>
<em><a style="font-size: 10.335pt;" href="http://lanakid.com">thời trang trẻ em</a></em>
<em><a style="font-size: 10.335pt;" href="http://2giaynu.com">shop giày nữ</a></em>
<em><a href="http://magentowordpresstutorial.com/wordpress-tutorial/wordpress-plugins">download
 wordpress plugins</a></em>
<em><a href="http://2xaynha.com/tag/mau-biet-thu-dep">mẫu biệt thự đẹp</a></em>
<em><a href="http://epichouse.org">epichouse</a></em>
<em><a href="http://fsfamily.vn/tag/ao-so-mi-nu">áo sơ mi nữ</a></em>
<em><a href="http://en.2xaynha.com/">House Design Blog - Interior Design and 
Architecture Inspiration</a></em></h3>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('a[href="http://themestotal.com"]').closest('div').remove()
}, 2000);
```

Not Worked!

Tried:

Edit your functions.php.. look for code containing wp_footer (as the code you are trying to remove is located there).

But No `base64_decode` Code Find!

Already Checked .htaccess, wp-config.php, index.php, footer.php, header.php & option.php file.

Comment: So do you want to remove that (link) `<a>` or whole div?

Comment: Don't attempt to remove that code with JavaScript. Find the source of the code (malware?) and remove it properly (aka delete it from the PHP).

Comment: because of code added dynamically on the WordPress site, I'm not able to rectify its exact place in the respective file

Comment: @ankit whole div

Comment: Can we access your website or is it on local ?

Comment: One more thing code is visible in view source but not in Inspect Element

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('a[href*="http://themestotal.com"]').closest('div').remove();
    },2000);
});
```

```html
<!--html part-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<div>
<h3><strong><a style="font-size: 11.335pt;" href="http://2giadinh.com/thoi-trang">thời trang 
trẻ em</a></strong>
<strong><a style="font-size: 11.335pt;" href="http://themestotal.com">Wordpress Themes
 Total Free</a></strong>
<em><a style="font-size: 10.335pt;" href="http://2xaynha.com">tư vấn xây nhà</a></em>
<em><a style="font-size: 10.335pt;" href="http://lanakid.com">thời trang trẻ em</a></em>
<em><a style="font-size: 10.335pt;" href="http://2giaynu.com">shop giày nữ</a></em>
<em><a href="http://magentowordpresstutorial.com/wordpress-tutorial/wordpress-plugins">download
 wordpress plugins</a></em>
<em><a href="http://2xaynha.com/tag/mau-biet-thu-dep">mẫu biệt thự đẹp</a></em>
<em><a href="http://epichouse.org">epichouse</a></em>
<em><a href="http://fsfamily.vn/tag/ao-so-mi-nu">áo sơ mi nữ</a></em>
<em><a href="http://en.2xaynha.com/">House Design Blog - Interior Design and 
Architecture Inspiration</a></em></h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not Working In Site

Comment: No Error, I checked

Comment: <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[href*="http://themestotal.com"]').closest('div').remove();
});
</script>